# Como justificar o texto em uma TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

É possível justificar (alinhar) o texto de um `TextView`? Além de justificar, quero aplicar outros tipos de formatação.

Comment: depende da sua necessidade em específico, da uma olhada nesta pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `TextView` não suporta este tipo de alinhamento.

Você pode fazer um aplicativo baseado em HTML ao invés de `TextView`, como sugere este link:

- [O unico caminho, como alinhar um texto de bloco no Android?](http://www.seal.io/2010/12/only-way-how-to-align-text-in-block-in.html)
- [Can I set property of Textview like justify?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12226299/1518921)

main.java:

```
package cz.seal.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Main extends Activity
{
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    

        String text = "<html><body>"
               + "<p align=\"justify\">"                
               + getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum) 
               + "</p> "
               + "</body></html>";

        mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Se os acentos não funcionarem, você pode tentar trocar o utf-8 pelo iso-8859-1, assim:

```
mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "iso-8859-1");
```

Comment: no meu código ele funcionou, porém, não conseguiu identificar os acentos, ou seja, o enconding utf-8...

Comment: @Everton acho que você tem que trocar o `mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");` por `mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html", "iso-8859-1");`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sua afirmação na frase inicial está  incorreta. O `TextView` suporta sim, alinhamento a direita a esquerda e centralizada. É melhor alterar senão o pessoal pode confundir.

Comment: @AckLay foi uma palavra perdida, eu queria dizer não suporta este tipo de alinhamento.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @Guilherme está correta, porém, no meu caso, para o android identificar o enconding utilizei...

```
mWebView.loadData(text,"text/html;charset=UTF-8",null);
```